# Dual boot Windows and Ubuntu on separate drives

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-8, easybcd

I have two HDDs, one with my Windows 8.1 install on it. I installed Ubuntu 15.04 on the second HDD by creating a UEFI bootable USB and installing it that way. There was no option to **Install alongside Windows** etc, so I just did a clean install on the second HDD. To try and create a dual boot system I downloaded EasyBCD and followed a tutorial about adding a Linux boot loader, now when I select load into Linux it comes up with terminal with

```
GRUB >
```

Any suggestions as to how I can run both Win 8.1 and Ubuntu on separate HDDs?

Comment: Run both at once?  Not possible without Virtual Box or VMware.

Comment: @Daniel I think he (or she!) is referring to a dual boot system :)

Comment: Wording is vague... but ^that makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you used EasyBCD, as it's really not necessary in this case. It appears to be that you have been booted to a Grub shell. Take a look at [this](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/776643-how-to-rescue-a-non-booting-grub-2-on-linux/) for how you should boot to your Linux HDD. Once you do that, run (in a terminal):

```
sudo update-grub
```

and it should automatically add entries to your Grub configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I couldn't figure out the EasyBCD thing, I think it was creating a grub boot for the SSD where Windows is installed. Instead when BIOS is booting, I select the SSD where Linux is installed and it loads, likewise I do the same for Windows.